# Get-PnPProvisioningTemplate User Groups and Workflows

Tags: powershell, pnp, pnp-provision

In  my today's SharePoint situation I need to replicate an website from a dev environment into another dev environment (without content, only structures). I have been looking to the

> Get-PnPProvisioningTemplate

cmdlet of the SharePoint PnP Powershell. However it seems that the generated template doesn't include existing groups information nor workflows associated to the current lists, not even in the case of OOB workflows like "Approval". Is there a workaround for this using PnP or other existing tools?

Thanks in advance

UPDATE:
I have successfully generated the template with the groups information including the `-IncludeSiteGroups` flag. However workflows are still left out of the template, any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

When exporting site templates ensure you export to the pnp file format. The xml file format does not include workflows definitions.